# Should I crop or pad Tesseract OCR learning boxes

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I am currently teaching Tesseract v3.02 to recognise UK driver's license cards. I am using QT Box Editor to generate .box files so I can "train" tesseract to recognise the font and layout of these documents. So a question came up for me: Do I closely crop each letter, or would it be better to give it e.g. a 1px padding all-round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is "whatever seems to make the engine recognise text the best". Which you'll only know once you've compiled your *.traineddata file and tested it.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing with U.S. drivers licenses from a website's webcam.  I'm planning on using the commandline version so I can just call it from my site, but may end up using the API.  In either event, can I train tesseract on where to look on licenses for the name, address, and DOB but then not use a graphical interface to read it?  Basically, still read the image with the commandline, but teach it where to look?

Comment: I don't know. You'd probably have to ask the developer that. I ended up using another (premium) package that actually tells you the pixel coordinates of each word it finds. And from that, I can use a predefined template to figure out what the word is supposed to be. So in effect it tells ME where it found the word, and I know that if that falls inside the bounds for ID number, that it is in fact an ID number.